# Android how to make EditText editable inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` with edit text in each items and I want to know how can I make the `EditText` editable.. It seems to work fine if I set the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` into the manifest but only on some devices. On some devices the soft keyboard covers the edittext.

On the other side, if I don't put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest, the `EditText` looses focus after the soft keyboard is displayed and I have to touch the `EditText` multiple times to make it selected and can write in it.

Please help me solve this.

**Note:** I've seen this post: [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview) and nothing helped from there and I have totally other problem than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround for this though.. maybe will help someone

```
public class EditTextListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /* notes list */
    private ArrayList<SomeData> mSomeData = null;
    /* layout inflater instance */
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    /* activity context */
    private Context mContext;

    /* ensure that this constant is greater than the maximum list size */
    private static final int DEFAULT_ID_VALUE = -1;
    /* used to keep the note edit text row id within the list */
    private int mNoteId = DEFAULT_ID_VALUE;

    /**
     * EditTextListAdapter adapter class constructor
     *
     * @param context               activity context
     */
    public FirstTimesListAdapter(Context context) {

        /* get a layout inflater instance */
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        /* load the data */
        mSomeData = SomeData.instance().getData(); 
        /* keep the context */
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the selected item
     *
     * @return selected item
     */
    public int getSelectedItem() {
        return mSelectedItem;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mSomeData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mSomeData.get(i);
    }

    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public View getView(final int index, View recycledView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (recycledView == null) {
            /* inflate the list item */
            recycledView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_with_edit_text, viewGroup, false);
            /* get link to the view holder views */
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.note = (EditText) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.first_times_note);
            recycledView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            /* reuse the same views we load the first time */
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) recycledView.getTag();
        }

        /* display some notes */
        viewHolder.note.setText(mSomeData.getNotes());

        /* if the last id is set, the edit text from this list item was pressed */
        if (mNoteId == index) { 

            /* make the edit text recive focus */
            viewHolder.note.requestFocusFromTouch();
            /* make the edit text's cursor to appear at the end of the text */
            viewHolder.note.setSelection(viewHolder.note.getText().length());

            /* reset the last id to default value */
            mNoteId = DEFAULT_ID_VALUE;
        }

        /* set a touch listener on the edit text just to record the index of the edit text that was pressed */
        viewHolder.note.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    /* get the index of the touched list item */
                    mNoteId = index;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return recycledView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {        
        /* note input */
        EditText note;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

After unsuccessfully trying to create an interface with `EditTexts` inside a `ListView` all I can say to you is "Don't!". You'll be in much more trouble when you have enough items that you have to scroll your `ListView`, focus will jump here and there, you'll have to save your `EditText`'s state and so on. It seems like general idea is that using `EditText` in `ListView` is not worth it.

After quite a bit of research I can suggest the following method that helped me:
I've inherited `ListView` and overrided layoutChildren method, inside it I do the following:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    final EditText tv = (EditText)this.getTag();
    if (tv != null)
    {
        Log.d("RUN", "posting delayed");
        this.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("RUN", "requesting focus in runnable");
                tv.requestFocusFromTouch();
                tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , tv.getWidth(), tv.getHeight(), 0));
                tv.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , tv.getWidth(), tv.getHeight(), 0));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I know which `EditText` should get the focus (I know this when my adapters getView is called) I set this particular `EditText` as a tag to `ListView`. Then ListView lays out itself and my post thread is queued. It runs and requests focus, however since it wasn't enough in my case, I also generate two `MotionEvents` that simply simulate a tap. Apparently this is enough to make the soft keyboard appear.
The reasons behind this are explained in an answer here:
[Android Actionbar Tabs and Keyboard Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087715/android-actionbar-tabs-and-keyboard-focus)