# Save listview to txt file

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to save all the items in my ListView to a text file. I am making an item then saving it on this button click.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.addItem:

            items.add(new ListViewItem() {{

                ThumbnailResource = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Title = et.getText().toString();
                SubTitle = "Item2 Description";

            }});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            // add-write text into file
            try {
                fileout = openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                outputWriter.write(et.getText().toString());
                outputWriter.close();

                //display file saved message
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        break;
```

Then When the person exits out of the app and goes back in, this code in on create adds the list item back.

```
  try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String start="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            start +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        final String finalStart = start;
        items.add(new ListViewItem() {{

            ThumbnailResource = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            Title = finalStart;
            SubTitle = "Item2 Description";

        }});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), start,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is it saves only one ListView item at a time. not all of them even though it saves after every button click. How do I get it to save all he items to the txt file. Not just the most recent one?

Thanks.

Here is all my code:

MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements 
 View.OnClickListener{

EditText et;

Button bt;

ListView lv;

List<ListViewItem> items;

CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

FileOutputStream fileout;

OutputStreamWriter outputWriter;

static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);

    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String start="";
        int charRead;

        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
            // char to string conversion
            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            start +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        final String finalStart = start;
        items.add(new ListViewItem() {{

            ThumbnailResource = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            Title = finalStart;
            SubTitle = "Item2 Description";

        }});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), start,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long arg3) {
            removeItemFromList(position);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.addItem:

            items.add(new ListViewItem() {{

                ThumbnailResource = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Title = et.getText().toString();
                SubTitle = "Item2 Description";

            }});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            // add-write text into file
            try {
                fileout = openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                outputWriter.write(et.getText().toString());
                outputWriter.close();

                //display file saved message
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        break;
    }

}

class ListViewItem {

        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String SubTitle;
}

protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
    final int deletePosition = position;

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

            // main code on after clicking yes
            items.remove(deletePosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();

    }
}
```

CustomViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<MainActivity.ListViewItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<MainActivity.ListViewItem> items) {
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MainActivity.ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

    ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

    imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);

    txtTitle.setText(item.Title);

    txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);

    return vi;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you save it to file instead of save it to ShredPrefernces?

Comment: Anyway you could add method in onStop() of activity/fragment that looping on listView and save all the data.

Comment: How do I add that method to onstop

Comment: or shared preferences whichever is easier

Comment: The best way is to save the imformation on database here is example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284889/i-want-to-store-the-list-of-item-displayed-in-listview-to-android-sqlite-databas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your onStop:

```
 @Override
 public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
        ListViewItem item = items.get(i);
        edit.putString(Integer.toString(i), item.ThumbnailResource + "," + item.Title + "," + item.SubTitle);
    }
    edit.commit();
```

To retreive this data add something like that to your onResume():

```
SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String item = myPref.getString(Integer.toString(0), "empty");
    int i = 0;
    do {
        String[] result = item.split(",");
        ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
        listItem.ThumbnailResource = Integer.valueOf(result[0]);
        listItem.Title = result[1];
        listItem.SubTitle = result[2];
        items.add(listItem);
        i++;
        item = myPref.getString(Integer.toString(i), "empty");
    } while (!item.equals("empty"));
```

Comment: I feel like this will work but you are right the slit caused my app to force close on start. How should I split it so this doesn't heppen