# How to edit EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, baseadapter

I have a listview consists of TextView, EditText and Checkbox. the layout of each item in the listview is shown below. the problem i have now is that i can not 
edit the editText, when i touch the editText to edit it the cursor jumps away and i can not edit the value inside the editText.

to solve thi problem, i referred to some posts and I added the following two line to the EditText

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

but it did not solve the problem

please also have alook at the getView() method is is posted below.

please let me know how to solve this problem to edit the EditText

**item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        holder.et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et);

        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ItemDesign element = (ItemDesign) holder.cb.getTag();
                element.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });

        holder.cb.setTag(designList.get(position));
        holder.et.setTag(designList.get(position));
        holder.tv.setTag(designList.get(position));
        //holder.et.setFocusable(false);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).et.setTag(designList.get(position));
        ((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).tv.setTag(designList.get(position));
        ((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).cb.setTag(designList.get(position));
        //((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).et.setFocusable(false);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.tv.setText(designList.get(position).getTxt());
    holder.cb.setChecked(designList.get(position).isChecked());
    holder.et.setText(designList.get(position).getEtTxt());
    //holder.et.setFocusable(false);
    return view;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    EditText et;
}
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015853/android-how-to-make-edittext-editable-inside-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem have nothing to do with these three line of code that you add

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

you can remove them. the problem is with this line.you set `EditText` width to zero.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

change it and you are good to go

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Not in this case, as he is using layout-weight, so the width of 0dp is correct in this case.

Comment: @Mehran Zamani your problem is post answers without checking he has given layout_weigh

Comment: escape defining android:layout_width seems rational not set it to 0dp